# Deploy Smart Contract on Private Blockchain

Tags: private-blockchain, contract-deployment, truffle-contract

I have created a Private Block chain Server on AWS with one Peer. Now if I want to deploy a smart contract at my AWS Node from my local system, how can I do that?

Regards
AKM.

Comment: In order to access your blockchain node, you should have proper access to it. Make sure that the client which is running blockchain, is allowing remote access.

Comment: I have the same question? I have created a Private Block chain Server on AWS with one Peer. Now if I want to deploy a smart contract at my AWS Node from my local system, how can I do that? Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOte: **This is not recommened with production or main chain. Please follow the instructions if you know what are you doing.**

I generally recommend using third party tools like [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.4.24+commit.e67f0147.js) or [myEtherWallet](http://yetherwallet.com) to deploy smart contracts easily if you are in test environment.

So you can run geth with these flags

```
--rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport "9816" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "web3,eth,admin,debug,miner,personal,net" --wsorigins "*"
```

Now you can make 9816 port of your instance public for a while and connec remix or MEW for your geth instance and deploy your smart contracts easily. You can close rpc port once you are finished.

PS: If you are running main-net, do not expose RPC calls like this to an external environment. The best way is to deploy contract from your geth instance.

PS: You can follow the artcile for [Deploying contract using byteCode (MyEtherWallet and Remix)](http://eploying%20contract%20using%20byteCode%20(MyEtherWallet%20and%20Remix).)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using truffle you just need to change the truffle.js so that instead of pointing to your localhost testrpc points to your aws node:

can truffle.js

```
module.exports = {
networks: {
   development: {
    host: "localhost",  //put here your aws node ip
    port: 8545,         //make sure the port is open
    network_id: "*" // Match any network id or put the network id you 
                       //given during private network setup
    from:"Oxbkjfo38438990", //put the address which was generated 
                             //during private network deployment 
    gas:4600000 //This much gas can deploy almost everything so put 
                       //this
    }
  } };
```

Then do the normal truffle compile and truffle migrate.

Comment: Thanks @haduart. I am getting the below error while connecting with truffle.
Could not connect to your Ethereum client. Please check that your Ethereum client:
    - is running
    - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" option is used in geth)
    - is accessible over the network
    - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle.js)

Comment: @Armit-modi I don't know if this response could help you: [truffle how to detect test environments](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18983/truffle-how-to-detect-test-environment-while-running-smart-contract-test-cases)
If not also make sure that the post is publicly available from your EC2 node.